# How prominant is the year/week-cycle's effect on the number of questions?

Tags: support

[Come January the gym is packed](http://sirartwork.tumblr.com/post/106382392098/my-latest-comic-for-fit-happy-new-year). Now we are in July I find that I can get through all my workout without having to wait for a single machine or bench.

Is the same true of the SE site yet? Do we have a significant question increase in January? What about other times of the year? Is there a weekly trend?

(I understand If I had more credit I could view the site analytics but I think this is a interesting point for those not in the top 13)